# Loss of nerves in asthma

Tags: pathology, neurology, neurotransmitter, pathophysiology, pulmonology

[This site says:](http://atlasgeneticsoncology.org/Genes/GC_VIP.html)

> VIP [vasoactive intestinal peptide] nerves are absent in severely asthmatic subjects. Mice with targeted deletion of the VIP gene exhibit histopathologic features of airway inflammation (Said et al., 2010).

So can we consider asthma as a **neurodegenerative**  disorder?

What will be the mechanism of destruction of nerves if the above statement is true? If the above statement is not correct then how there is reduction in VIP ? I think of two possibilities either VIP is not synthesised in the neurons (Gene is down regulated, *if so, by what?*) or it is readily destroyed after its synthesis?

Could anyone please correct me?

Comment: You also have to consider if the nerves were there to begin with, and whether it's an issue of development rather than degeneration. I think an overarching suggestion is that while asthma is mediated by immune cells, there are other events including neurological that mediate the response. And this is for me [a good source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18498538), though not recent.